# Filter shipping methods by post code

Tags: shipping, plugin

Our website ships to the UK only. We use parcel force as our courier which prices are decided by the 3 different zones of the UK.

How can I create a plugin which hides/shows methods depending on the post code, or do any plugins already exists.

I can't find any information on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might able to use Magento table rates but keep in mind that table rates will be its own shipping method in Magento.

Table rates will allow you to select weight vs destination. In this mode you can use a country code(UK in your case) and a zip code range as well as weight range inside a CSV file, this file can than be uploaded.

Magento 1 documentation M1CE
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/table-rates.html

Magento 2 documentation M2CE 
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

This might only work if your areas have actual zip codes. For Germany this works just fine.